Rstudio Error starting correctly after installing older version of R
I am facing an issue after installing Rstudio
I installed a tar.gz verison of R (4.3.0 released on April 2023. The latest version is 4.4.0 ) then I installed R studio but "Error starting R" appears. Here is a screenshot:

Here is a copy of the problem report:
## R Session Startup Failure Report

### RStudio Version

RStudio 2024.04.0-daily+603 "Chocolate Cosmos " (e0e7d4fd, 2024-03-18) for Ubuntu Focal

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) rstudio/2024.04.0-daily+603 Chrome/120.0.6099.291 Electron/28.2.6 Safari/537.36

### Error message

[No error available]

### Process Output

The R session exited with code 127. 

Error output:

/usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/rsession: error while loading shared libraries: libR.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Standard output:

[No output emitted]

### Logs

*/home/sherwood/.local/share/rstudio/log/rsession-sherwood.log*

2024-05-06T01:08:53.228638Z [rsession-sherwood] WARNING ASSERTION FAILED: !posix::pthread_mutex_lock(&m); LOGGED FROM: void rstudio_boost::recursive_mutex::lock() /opt/rstudio-tools/x86_64/boost/boost_1_83_0/include/boost/thread/pthread/recursive_mutex.hpp:108
2024-05-06T01:08:53.229280Z [rsession-sherwood] WARNING ASSERTION FAILED: !posix::pthread_mutex_unlock(&m); LOGGED FROM: void rstudio_boost::recursive_mutex::unlock() /opt/rstudio-tools/x86_64/boost/boost_1_83_0/include/boost/thread/pthread/recursive_mutex.hpp:113
2024-05-06T01:08:53.229280Z [rsession-sherwood] WARNING ASSERTION FAILED: !posix::pthread_mutex_unlock(&m); LOGGED FROM: void rstudio_boost::recursive_mutex::unlock() /opt/rstudio-tools/x86_64/boost/boost_1_83_0/include/boost/thread/pthread/recursive_mutex.hpp:113
What I followed was what a user did on a comment in github Rstudio issues: #13184 (comment)

Downloaded rstudio-2024.04.0-daily-603-amd64 from https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-ide-build/electron/focal/amd64/rstudio-2024.04.0-daily-603-amd64.deb

But had no success following his steps. The same error is appearing.


Here some info about R:

R.home()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R"

Session info:

sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS


Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/local/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/local/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.so; LAPACK version 3.11.0


locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C
[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NAME=C
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C


time zone: America/Lima
tzcode source: system (glibc)


attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base


loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.0

Do you have any ideas how to solve it, please?
